# Forecast done by Holt's winter method has seasonality in error (Auto correlation graph)

Tags: forecasting

I am doing forecasting for six month daily data for item sales of which increases on friday and saturday.  I am using Holts Winters method and have done the forecasting getting Thiel's U Statistics value of 0.62.

Plotting the ACF graph for the error, i find that the peaks occur in 7, 14, 21 periods which indicates that some seasonality error is present in my calculations.

I have below two questions:

1. Is my forecast good enough? Some parameters are mentioned below:

ME  0.25
MAE 3.38
MAPE    23.77
MSE 19.20
U Stat  0.623038794

Alpha   0.494203004
Beta    0.691687311
Gamma   0.00617242

Which approach would provide better results?  I am doing the exercise in excel.

2. What would you suggest looking into the image of the ACF attached herewith?  How can the forecast be improved?  There are 176 data points.
   [![ACF graph for errors of forecasting][1]][1]
   Thanks in advance,

Best regards,
Purav

Data for the forecasting:

Date    Yt
3/2/2015    15
3/3/2015    19
3/4/2015    18
3/5/2015    14
3/6/2015    23
3/7/2015    26
3/8/2015    24
3/9/2015    15
3/10/2015   23
3/11/2015   16
3/12/2015   17
3/13/2015   22
3/14/2015   24
3/15/2015   19
3/16/2015   12
3/17/2015   12
3/18/2015   11
3/19/2015   15
3/20/2015   21
3/21/2015   25
3/22/2015   25
3/23/2015   18
3/24/2015   15
3/25/2015   20
3/26/2015   17
3/27/2015   23
3/28/2015   25
3/29/2015   19
3/30/2015   18
3/31/2015   14
4/1/2015    12
4/2/2015    9
4/3/2015    31
4/4/2015    22
4/5/2015    25
4/6/2015    9
4/7/2015    10
4/8/2015    28
4/9/2015    16
4/10/2015   18
4/11/2015   17
4/12/2015   22
4/13/2015   20
4/14/2015   15
4/15/2015   18
4/16/2015   19
4/17/2015   17
4/18/2015   22
4/19/2015   33
4/20/2015   11
4/21/2015   10
4/22/2015   13
4/23/2015   17
4/24/2015   23
4/25/2015   22
4/26/2015   24
4/27/2015   11
4/28/2015   13
4/29/2015   12
4/30/2015   24
5/1/2015    20
5/2/2015    13
5/3/2015    24
5/4/2015    8
5/5/2015    14
5/6/2015    19
5/7/2015    12
5/8/2015    15
5/9/2015    22
5/10/2015   15
5/11/2015   12
5/12/2015   13
5/13/2015   14
5/14/2015   17
5/15/2015   20
5/16/2015   20
5/17/2015   23
5/18/2015   16
5/19/2015   8
5/20/2015   23
5/21/2015   20
5/22/2015   15
5/23/2015   13
5/24/2015   13
5/25/2015   6
5/26/2015   15
5/27/2015   15
5/28/2015   14
5/29/2015   22
5/30/2015   31
5/31/2015   24
6/1/2015    9
6/2/2015    14
6/3/2015    16
6/4/2015    14
6/5/2015    14
6/6/2015    27
6/7/2015    22
6/8/2015    14
6/9/2015    17
6/10/2015   20
6/11/2015   15
6/12/2015   9
6/13/2015   15
6/14/2015   25
6/15/2015   13
6/16/2015   17
6/17/2015   15
6/18/2015   13
6/19/2015   22
6/20/2015   24
6/21/2015   20
6/22/2015   10
6/23/2015   10
6/24/2015   22
6/25/2015   24
6/26/2015   23
6/27/2015   25
6/28/2015   19
6/29/2015   14
6/30/2015   19
7/1/2015    12
7/2/2015    15
7/3/2015    27
7/4/2015    25
7/5/2015    14
7/6/2015    11
7/7/2015    20
7/8/2015    16
7/9/2015    11
7/10/2015   16
7/11/2015   31
7/12/2015   16
7/13/2015   11
7/14/2015   14
7/15/2015   22
7/16/2015   14
7/17/2015   22
7/18/2015   19
7/19/2015   21
7/20/2015   16
7/21/2015   16
7/22/2015   18
7/23/2015   9
7/24/2015   29
7/25/2015   25
7/26/2015   16
7/27/2015   12
7/28/2015   14
7/29/2015   26
7/30/2015   11
7/31/2015   18
8/1/2015    25
8/2/2015    22
8/3/2015    9
8/4/2015    20
8/5/2015    15
8/6/2015    16
8/7/2015    34
8/8/2015    25
8/9/2015    21
8/10/2015   13
8/11/2015   12
8/12/2015   18
8/13/2015   18
8/14/2015   24
8/15/2015   27
8/16/2015   15
8/17/2015   18
8/18/2015   14
8/19/2015   19
8/20/2015   17
8/21/2015   20
8/22/2015   20
8/23/2015   22
8/24/2015   14
8/25/2015   18
8/26/2015   11
8/27/2015   22
8/28/2015   22
8/29/2015   33
8/30/2015   22
8/31/2015   12
9/1/2015    8
9/2/2015    14
9/3/2015    17
9/4/2015    15
9/5/2015    29
9/6/2015    10
9/7/2015    11
9/8/2015    19
9/9/2015    17
9/10/2015   10
9/11/2015   36
9/12/2015   19
9/13/2015   17
9/14/2015   12
9/15/2015   12
9/16/2015   23
9/17/2015   13
9/18/2015   20
9/19/2015   15
9/20/2015   13
9/21/2015   15
9/22/2015   17
9/23/2015   14
9/24/2015   21
9/25/2015   21
9/26/2015   30
9/27/2015   19
9/28/2015   18
9/29/2015   11
9/30/2015   16
10/1/2015   19
10/2/2015   24
10/3/2015   21
10/4/2015   16
10/5/2015   14
10/6/2015   12
10/7/2015   13
10/8/2015   14
10/9/2015   20
10/10/2015  29
10/11/2015  20
10/12/2015  9
10/13/2015  8
10/14/2015  6
10/15/2015  15
10/16/2015  18
10/17/2015  22
10/18/2015  17
10/19/2015  9
10/20/2015  13
10/21/2015  16
10/22/2015  12
10/23/2015  12
10/24/2015  23
10/25/2015  27
10/26/2015  10
10/27/2015  15
10/28/2015  18
10/29/2015  12
10/30/2015  17
10/31/2015  16
11/1/2015   8
11/2/2015   12
11/3/2015   13
11/4/2015   11
11/5/2015   12
11/6/2015   15
11/7/2015   18
11/8/2015   13
11/9/2015   6
11/10/2015  20
11/11/2015  14
11/12/2015  13
11/13/2015  18
11/14/2015  8
11/15/2015  9
11/16/2015  9
11/17/2015  14
11/18/2015  12
11/19/2015  6
11/20/2015  17
11/21/2015  16
11/22/2015  17
11/23/2015  11
11/24/2015  16
11/25/2015  14
11/26/2015  13
11/27/2015  15
11/28/2015  20
11/29/2015  16
11/30/2015  7
12/1/2015   11
12/2/2015   7
12/3/2015   12
12/4/2015   25
12/5/2015   20
12/6/2015   17
12/7/2015   11
12/8/2015   15
12/9/2015   10
12/10/2015  23
12/11/2015  17
12/12/2015  13
12/13/2015  17
12/14/2015  13
12/15/2015  18
12/16/2015  12
12/17/2015  12
12/18/2015  17
12/19/2015  12
12/20/2015  19
12/21/2015  15
12/22/2015  15
12/23/2015  16
12/24/2015  17
12/25/2015  27
12/26/2015  15
12/27/2015  19
12/28/2015  8
12/29/2015  12
12/30/2015  18
12/31/2015  48
1/1/2016    13
1/2/2016    18
1/3/2016    14
1/4/2016    12
1/5/2016    11
1/6/2016    6
1/7/2016    14
1/8/2016    17
1/9/2016    21
1/10/2016   16
1/11/2016   7
1/12/2016   12
1/13/2016   7
1/14/2016   12
1/15/2016   13
1/16/2016   15
1/17/2016   14
1/18/2016   8
1/19/2016   11
1/20/2016   11
1/21/2016   15
1/22/2016   10
1/23/2016   23
1/24/2016   13
1/25/2016   14
1/26/2016   16
1/27/2016   14
1/28/2016   13
1/29/2016   14
1/30/2016   17
1/31/2016   19
2/1/2016    7
2/2/2016    9
2/3/2016    7
2/4/2016    8
2/5/2016    18
2/6/2016    15
2/7/2016    14
2/8/2016    8
2/9/2016    12
2/10/2016   16
2/11/2016   14
2/12/2016   16
2/13/2016   17
2/14/2016   8
2/15/2016   7
2/16/2016   9
2/17/2016   6
2/18/2016   8
2/19/2016   12
2/20/2016   12
2/21/2016   20
2/22/2016   4
2/23/2016   11
2/24/2016   14
2/25/2016   10
2/26/2016   16
2/27/2016   11
2/28/2016   13
2/29/2016   14
3/1/2016    9

Comment: How can we tell whether a forecast is "good enough" when you don't present the forecast, the data, or tell us how to assess "goodness"?